# How add conditional in barplot?

Tags: r

I want to get all those Quantity of field CompanyName > 40

NOTE: daots2(MY TABLE) is variable

```
barplot(daots2$QUANTITY[daots2$UNITPRICE > 40], names.arg = daots2$CompanyName,
  beside = F, ylab = 'Frecuency' , main = 'Cantidad')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceu8z.png)

this my data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYk1K.png)

Comment: Please give the error message and data as text rather than as images

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend subsetting your data using `dplyr`:

```
# install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

The following will give you the **sum** of `QUANTITY` for all `UNITPRICE` that is `> 40`.

```
plotData <- daots2 %>%
                   filter(UNITPRICE > 40) %>%
                   summarise(quantSum = sum(QUANTITY))
```

The following will give you the **count** of the number of companies for which `UNITPRICE` that is `> 40`.

```
plotData <- daots2 %>%
                   filter(UNITPRICE > 40) %>%
                   summarise(uniqueCompany = n_distinct(ProductName))
```

Comment: I put my image of my data. THANK YOU .I want to GET THE QUANTITY OF THESE COMPANIES  that have the UNITPRICE > 40

Comment: Angel, I have edited my answer to reflect this need.